# MobX - Unable to set an observable

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I am new to MobX and I try to create a small application to experiment with mobX.

I rewrote the question to make it clear

I declare 4 observables and 4 actions.
This is the Store I build
If i initialize questionTotal in the constructor, it's work.

This is the Store I build

```
export default class QuestionStore {
questionTotal =  0;
questionUnAnswered = 0;
loading = false;
listQuestion = new Array<QuestionData>();

constructor() {
    console.log("Constructeur QuestionStore");
    this.setAllQuestion();
    makeAutoObservable(this);
}

// Indicateur que nous sommes en attente de données.
setLoading = (arg: boolean) => {
    console.log("In setLoading");
    this.loading = arg;
}

// Initialise listQuestion, le compteur de question et le nombre sans réponse.
setAllQuestion() {
    console.log("Enter setAllQuestion");
    this.setLoading(true);
    this.listQuestion = questions;
    this.questionTotal = this.listQuestion.length;
    this.questionUnAnswered = this.listQuestion.filter(x => x.answers.length === 0).length;
    console.log("in setAllQuestion taille:" + this.questionTotal);
    this.setLoading(false);
}
```

}

when I tried to set it from the App,
if(!loading ) runInAction(() => { setAllQuestion() });

it issue the following error and the page is not display

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGInK.jpg)

We can see from the trace that setAllQuestion is call twice and setLoading could not be call.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setLoading')

Comment: How do you run it, can you please the code? Like how exactly you are invoking `setLoading`? I suspect that you are destructuring and losing context for that function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is losing context (`this`), you need to [read about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to understand how it works. You destructured this function from the store and it is not bound to it anymore.

The most common way is to define all actions as arrow functions, like that:

```
// Use arrow function to define method
setAllQuestion = () => {
    this.setLoading(true);
    this.listQuestion = questions;
    this.questionTotal = this.listQuestion.length;
    this.questionUnAnswered = this.listQuestion.filter(x => x.answers.length === 0).length;
    this.setLoading(false);
}
```

That way you don't need to worry about the context, it will be automatically bound to the current class. Just like you did with `setLoading` action.